# How do I use Comparator to define a custom sort order?

Tags: java, sorting, enums

I want to develop a sorting demo for car list. I am using data table to display car list. Now actually I want to sort the list by car color. Here it is not sort by alphabetic order. I want to use my custom sorting order like Red car come first, then Blue, etc.

For that I try to use Java [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) and [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) but it allows to sort in alphabetic order only.

So, can any one guide me the way to implement the technique to use so that the sorting becomes faster.

```
class Car implements Comparable<Car>
{
    private String name;
    private String color;

    public Car(String name, String color){
        this.name = name;
        this.color = color;
    }

    //Implement the natural order for this class
    public int compareTo(Car c) {
        return name.compareTo(c.name);
    }

    static class ColorComparator implements Comparator<Car> {
        public int compare(Car c1, Car c2) {
            String a1 = c1.color;
            String a2 = c2.color;
            return a1.compareTo(a2);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Car> carList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> sortOrder = new ArrayList<>();

        carList.add(new Car("Ford","Silver"));
        carList.add(new Car("Tes","Blue"));
        carList.add(new Car("Honda","Magenta"));

        sortOrder.add("Silver");
        sortOrder.add("Magenta");
        sortOrder.add("Blue");

        // Now here I am confuse how to implement my custom sort             
    }
}
```

Answer (score 115):

I recommend you create an enum for your car colours instead of using Strings and the natural ordering of the enum will be the order in which you declare the constants.

```
public enum PaintColors {
    SILVER, BLUE, MAGENTA, RED
}
```

and

```
 static class ColorComparator implements Comparator<CarSort>
 {
     public int compare(CarSort c1, CarSort c2)
     {
         return c1.getColor().compareTo(c2.getColor());
     }
 }
```

You change the String to PaintColor and then in main your car list becomes:

```
carList.add(new CarSort("Ford Figo",PaintColor.SILVER));

...

Collections.sort(carList, new ColorComparator());
```

Comment: how would i run this example.PaintColors is not accessed in ColorComparator.could you illustrate how the main method would look like.

Comment: what is the output ? is it always SILVER first ?

Comment: @Deepak: yes, the natural order of `enum` values is the order in which its values are defined.

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd I don't think that relying on the natural ordering of enums is a best practice.

Comment: @mike I disagree, but there are valid arguments for both points of view

Comment: @mike mitigation add a javadoc comment to the enum referencing the comparator - it may prevent someone arbitarily changing the order and breaking code...

Comment: Using java8 streams and lambdas, we could do with just this:


```List<Car> sorted = carList
          .stream()
          .sorted((c1, c2) -> c1.getColor().compareTo(c2.getColor()))
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 79):

How about this:

```
List<String> definedOrder = // define your custom order
    Arrays.asList("Red", "Green", "Magenta", "Silver");

Comparator<Car> comparator = new Comparator<Car>(){

    @Override
    public int compare(final Car o1, final Car o2){
        // let your comparator look up your car's color in the custom order
        return Integer.valueOf(
            definedOrder.indexOf(o1.getColor()))
            .compareTo(
                Integer.valueOf(
                    definedOrder.indexOf(o2.getColor())));
    }
};
```

In principle, I agree that using an `enum` is an even better approach, but this version is more flexible as it lets you define different sort orders.

**Update**

[Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) has this functionality baked into its [`Ordering`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html) class:

```
List<String> colorOrder = ImmutableList.of("red","green","blue","yellow");
final Ordering<String> colorOrdering = Ordering.explicit(colorOrder);
Comparator<Car> comp = new Comparator<Car>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Car o1, Car o2) {
        return colorOrdering.compare(o1.getColor(),o2.getColor());
    }
};
```

This version is a bit less verbose.

---

**Update again**

Java 8 makes the Comparator even less verbose:

```
Comparator<Car> carComparator = Comparator.comparing(
        c -> definedOrder.indexOf(c.getColor()));
```

Comment: Can u please look into this question as well. THanks you.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61934313/java-priorityqueue-for-jsonobject

Comment: `Comparator<Car> carComparator = Comparator.comparing(
        c -> definedOrder.indexOf(c.getColor())); ` is throwing compile errors

Comment: @SantosshKumhar here's a working example: https://ideone.com/frUbym

Answer (score 27):

Comparator in line ...

```
List<Object> objList = findObj(name);
Collections.sort(objList, new Comparator<Object>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Object a1, Object a2) {
        return a1.getType().compareToIgnoreCase(a2.getType());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 15):

I think this can be done as follows:

```
class ColorComparator implements Comparator<CarSort>
{
    private List<String> sortOrder;
    public ColorComparator (List<String> sortOrder){
        this.sortOrder = sortOrder;
    }

    public int compare(CarSort c1, CarSort c2)
    {
        String a1 = c1.getColor();
        String a2 = c2.getColor();
        return sortOrder.indexOf(a1) - sortOrder.indexOf(a2);
     }
 }
```

For sorting use this:

```
Collections.sort(carList, new ColorComparator(sortOrder));
```

Answer (score 8):

I had to do something similar to Sean and ilalex's answer.
But I had too many options to explicitly define the sort order for and only needed to float certain entries to the front of the list ... in the specified (non-natural) order.
Hopefully this is helpful to someone else.

```
public class CarComparator implements Comparator<Car> {

    //sort these items in this order to the front of the list 
    private static List<String> ORDER = Arrays.asList("dd", "aa", "cc", "bb");

    public int compare(final Car o1, final Car o2) {
        int result = 0;
        int o1Index = ORDER.indexOf(o1.getName());
        int o2Index = ORDER.indexOf(o2.getName());
        //if neither are found in the order list, then do natural sort
        //if only one is found in the order list, float it above the other
        //if both are found in the order list, then do the index compare
        if (o1Index < 0 && o2Index < 0) result = o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
        else if (o1Index < 0) result = 1;
        else if (o2Index < 0) result = -1;
        else result = o1Index - o2Index;
        return result;
    }

//Testing output: dd,aa,aa,cc,bb,bb,bb,a,aaa,ac,ac,ba,bd,ca,cb,cb,cd,da,db,dc,zz
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I will do something like this:

```
List<String> order = List.of("Red", "Green", "Magenta", "Silver");

Comparator.comparing(Car::getColor(), Comparator.comparingInt(c -> order.indexOf(c)))
```

All credits go to @Sean Patrick Floyd :)

Answer (score 4):

In Java 8 you can do something like this:

You first need an Enum:

```
public enum Color {
    BLUE, YELLOW, RED
}
```

Car class:

```
public class Car {

    Color color;

    ....

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
    }
}
```

And then, using your car list, you can simply do:

```
Collections.sort(carList, Comparator:comparing(CarSort::getColor));
```

Comment: This is not a custom sort.

Comment: Besides, it's not a "functional" way of doing it... this has side affects!!

Answer (score 2):

Define one Enum Type as

```
public enum Colors {
     BLUE, SILVER, MAGENTA, RED
}
```

Change data type of `color` from `String` to `Colors`
Change return type and argument type of getter and setter method of color to `Colors`

Define comparator type as follows

```
static class ColorComparator implements Comparator<CarSort>
{
    public int compare(CarSort c1, CarSort c2)
    {
        return c1.getColor().compareTo(c2.getColor());
    }
}
```

after adding elements to List, call sort method of Collection by passing list and comparator objects as arguments

i.e, `Collections.sort(carList, new ColorComparator());` 
then print using `ListIterator`.

full class implementation is as follows:

```
package test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;    
import java.util.ListIterator;

public class CarSort implements Comparable<CarSort>{

    String name;
    Colors color;

    public CarSort(String name, Colors color){
        this.name = name;
        this.color = color;
    } 

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Colors getColor() {
        return color;
    }
    public void setColor(Colors color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    //Implement the natural order for this class
    public int compareTo(CarSort c)
    {
        return getName().compareTo(c.getName());
    }

    static class ColorComparator implements Comparator<CarSort>
    {
        public int compare(CarSort c1, CarSort c2)
        {
            return c1.getColor().compareTo(c2.getColor());
        }
    }

    public enum Colors {
         BLUE, SILVER, MAGENTA, RED
    }

     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
         List<CarSort> carList = new ArrayList<CarSort>();
         List<String> sortOrder = new ArrayList<String>();

         carList.add(new CarSort("Ford Figo",Colors.SILVER));
         carList.add(new CarSort("Santro",Colors.BLUE));
         carList.add(new CarSort("Honda Jazz",Colors.MAGENTA));
         carList.add(new CarSort("Indigo V2",Colors.RED));
         Collections.sort(carList, new ColorComparator());

         ListIterator<CarSort> itr=carList.listIterator();
         while (itr.hasNext()) {
            CarSort carSort = (CarSort) itr.next();
            System.out.println("Car colors: "+carSort.getColor());
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using just simple loops:

```
public static void compareSortOrder (List<String> sortOrder, List<String> listToCompare){
        int currentSortingLevel = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<listToCompare.size(); i++){
            System.out.println("Item from list: " + listToCompare.get(i));
            System.out.println("Sorting level: " + sortOrder.get(currentSortingLevel));
            if (listToCompare.get(i).equals(sortOrder.get(currentSortingLevel))){

            } else {
                try{
                    while (!listToCompare.get(i).equals(sortOrder.get(currentSortingLevel)))
                        currentSortingLevel++;
                    System.out.println("Changing sorting level to next value: " + sortOrder.get(currentSortingLevel));
                } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){

                }

            }
        }
    }
```

And sort order in List

```
public static List<String> ALARMS_LIST = Arrays.asList(
            "CRITICAL",
            "MAJOR",
            "MINOR",
            "WARNING",
            "GOOD",
            "N/A");
```