# Customize compare function NSString?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, compare-and-swap

I want to sort array of string similar [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16541314/sorting-an-array-of-string-with-custom-ordering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/rule.html)
in objective C, I think similar to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/rule.htmlThanks you.

Comment: Have you try something??

Comment: I create dictionary key:character, value: int, i use dictionary to sort. But like is slow, have any suggestion even use C pure? Thank you?

Comment: Comments are not for providing code. Edit your question and add the code, screenshot, whatever you have to it, explaining the problem clearly, to get help.