# Issue with Sorting ArrayList using Collection

Tags: java, sorting, collections, arraylist, comparator

I am trying to sort VariantOptionData ArrayList using its one of parameter.

here is my `VariantOptionData`

```
public class VariantOptionData  implements java.io.Serializable 
{

   private Collection<VariantOptionQualifierData> variantOptionQualifiers;
   private StockData stock;
   private NGCPSizeEnum cs2;
}
```

And I want to sort this list using cs2 parameter. I am doing like this ..

```
List<VariantOptionData> allSizes = Converters.convertAll(style.getVariants(), getVariantOptionDataConverter());

Collections.sort(allSizes, new Comparator<VariantOptionData>()
{
        @Override
        public int compare(final VariantOptionData s1, final VariantOptionData s2)
        {
            return Integer.parseInt(s1.getCs2().getCode()) < Integer.parseInt(s1.getCs2().getCode()) ? s1.getCs2().getCode() : s2.getCs2().getCode();
        }
});
```

I know its wrong, but I am trying something like this but not able to understand how exactly Comparators are working. `cs2` is a enum fields which having code as a increment value. I want to sort this list using `Integer.parseInt(s1.getCs2().getCode())` increasing order. Please help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245093/using-comparator-to-make-custom-sort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the Javadoc for [`compare()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare(T,%20T)) you can find out how it is expected to work:

> *Compares its two arguments for order. Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second.*

To follow this rule, all you need to do is a simple subtraction:

```
    @Override
    public int compare(final VariantOptionData s1, final VariantOptionData s2)
    {
        return Integer.parseInt(s1.getCs2().getCode()) - Integer.parseInt(s2.getCs2().getCode());
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to return not the biggest value in comparator, but, for example substract them:

```
@Override
        public int compare(final VariantOptionData s1, final VariantOptionData s2)
        {
            return Integer.parseInt(s1.getCs2().getCode()) - Integer.parseInt(s2.getCs2().getCode());
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it is not working is that the `compare` method is wrong. You need to return the following: `0` if both elements are equal, a negative one if the first value is lower than the second, and a positive one if the first one is greater than the second.

```
@Override
public int compare(final VariantOptionData s1, final VariantOptionData s2) {
        return Integer.parseInt(s1.getCs2().getCode()) - Integer.parseInt(s2.getCs2().getCode());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, since we don't have some parts of your code, and we don't have a stacktrace neither, i'm going to try to help you with what i have.

Your code seems nice, you just need to return a number in `compare` method, and i just can see you need a getter method for the cs2 attribute in `VariantOptionData`, and it must have a "code" attribute too.

`Comparator` is an interface, that's why you are implementing the compare method while instanciating it, we call it "annonymous class". And the `Collections.sort` will sort it with the rule you implement inside the `compare` method.