# How to sort List<Object> by Object's properties?

Tags: java

Class `Task.java`:

```
    import java.util.Date;

    public class Task {

        public Long taskId;
        public Date startDate;

        public Task() {

        }

        public Task(Long taskId, Date startDate) {  
            this.taskId = taskId;
            this.startDate = startDate;
        }

        public Long getTaskId() {
            return taskId;
        }

        public void setTaskId(Long taskId) {
            this.taskId = taskId;
        }

        public Date getStartDate() {
            return startDate;
        }

        public void setStartDate(Date startDate) {
            this.startDate = startDate;
        }   

    }



Class `Test.java`
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        List<Task> subTaskList = new ArrayList<Task>();
        DateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Task t1 = new Task(34L, dateFormatter.parse("2013-09-20"));
        Task t2 = new Task(31L, dateFormatter.parse("2015-09-10"));
        Task t3 = new Task(1L, dateFormatter.parse("2015-09-13"));
        Task t4 = new Task(34L, dateFormatter.parse("2014-02-23"));     
        subTaskList.add(t1);
        subTaskList.add(t2);
        subTaskList.add(t3);
        subTaskList.add(t4);
    }   

}
```

How to sort `subTaskList` by `startDate`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245093/using-comparator-to-make-custom-sort

Comment: asked 1 min ago;

marked as duplicate by Sotirios Delimanolis 30 secs ago;

you gotta believe in search man.

Comment: Thank @Sotirios Delimanolis, you redirect me to the right way.