# What type collection use for sorted unique object in Java?

Tags: java, collections

I have simple object:

```
public class Vector3i {

    public int x, y, z;

    public Vector3i(int x, int y, int z) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }

}
```

What collection I need for sorted unique items?

Thank you for your help and advice.

Comment: How do you compare two instances of `Vector3i`?

Comment: using variables x, y, z.

Comment: This class doesn't override `equals` (and `hashCode`) method which will prevent you from seeing two vectors with similar parameters as equal which may cause problems with standard collections which should store unique elements like Sets.

Comment: TreeSet is usually used to store sorted unique objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sort unique object in java you're going to want to create you're own comparator. 
[Using comparator to make custom sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245093/using-comparator-to-make-custom-sort)