# Is there any way sorting an arraylist of objects in java without using Comparator or comparable?

Tags: java, loops, sorting, arraylist, collections

Is there any way sorting an arraylist of objects in java without using Comparator or comparable ,I have Student class as shown below i need to Sort the Students Objects based on their Age., Is it possible to Sort ? without using implementing Comparator  or Comparable in class

```
//Class of Students
//comparable or comparator Not implemented

 public class Student  {
        private String studentname;
        private int rollno;
        private int studentage;

        public Student(int rollno, String studentname, int studentage) {
             this.rollno = rollno;
             this.studentname = studentname;
             this.studentage = studentage;
        }

        public String getStudentname() {
             return studentname;
        }
        public void setStudentname(String studentname) {
        this.studentname = studentname;
        }
        public int getRollno() {
        return rollno;
        }
        public void setRollno(int rollno) {
        this.rollno = rollno;
        }
        public int getStudentage() {
        return studentage;
        }
        public void setStudentage(int studentage) {
        this.studentage = studentage;
        }   
    }


    import java.util.*;
    public class ArrayListSorting  {

         public static void main(String args[]){

         //Array of Student Objects
           ArrayList<Student> arraylist = new ArrayList<Student>();
           arraylist.add(new Student(223, "Chaitanya", 26));
           arraylist.add(new Student(245, "Rahul", 24));
           arraylist.add(new Student(209, "Ajeet", 32));

           Collections.sort(arraylist);

           for(Student str: arraylist){
                System.out.println(str.getStudentage());
           }
         }
    }
```

Comment: Can you use lambda functions? this is using the comparator but without writing much code.
`Collections.sort(list, (s1, s2) -> s1.getStudentage().compareTo(s2. getStudentage));`
Any specific reason you don't want to use the comparator ?

Comment: No, its not possible, except programming the algo by yourself

Comment: Are you sure that the statement `System.out.println(str);` works? I didn't know the `println()` function to be taking arguments of type `java.lang.Object`.

Comment: @HenningLuther How can you say it is impossible and name a possibility in the same sentence?

Comment: @zstring Tried on elitmus Test Editor but it doesn't worked out

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're coming from the most strict interpretation of this then the answer is still, and *always*, yes.

Sorting algorithms sort data without concern of the language they're implemented in. So, if you can't use any sneaky work around then the point of your exercise is to implement a sorting algorithm. Seems reasonable.

I'm not going to give you a sort algorithm. But, depending on how you want to go about it, you could provide a utility class (like Java does), accept an `ArrayList`, and sort it with your choice of sorting algo. You would obviously do this based on the age of the student.

`Lists.sort(yourArrayList);` : would be as good as anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to sort an `ArrayList` by using the `get()` and `set()` methods instead of `Comparable` and `Comparator`:

```
public class ArrayListSortWithoutComparator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList < Integer > arraylist = new ArrayList < Integer > ();

        arraylist.add(10);
        arraylist.add(5);
        arraylist.add(4);
        arraylist.add(2);

        for (int i = 0; i < arraylist.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = arraylist.size() - 1; j > i; j--) {
                if (arraylist.get(i) > arraylist.get(j)) {
                    int tmp = arraylist.get(i);
                    arraylist.set(i,arraylist.get(j));
                    arraylist.set(j,tmp);
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i : arraylist) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2
4
5
10
```

Comment: This is Bubble sort. Could you mention this in your answer?

Comment: i agree with you , my solution is bubble sort

Answer (score 0):

No, if the `ArrayList` is of ***custom object type*** then in such case you have two options for sorting - `Comparable` and `Comparator` interfaces.

However you can use `Collections.sort()` method to sort a ***simple array list***.

Comment: **Or** you implement sorting yourself, which seems to be the goal of the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is **Yes**. Here's how: You can simply use a `Selection Sort` technique to iterate over the ArrayList like you do for an array.

```
for(int i=0;i<arraylist.size()-1;i++){
    int m = i;
    for(int j=i+1;j<arraylist.size();j++){
        if(araylist.get(m).studentage > arraylist.get(j).studentage)
            m = j;
    }
    //swapping elements at position i and m
    Student temp = arraylist.get(i);
    arraylist.set(i, arraylist.get(m));
    arraylist.set(m, temp);
}
```

This would sort the Student objects in ascending order of ages.

Comment: " i need to Sort the Students Objects **based on their Age**" :) But I guess you can leave the change up for OP's practice.

Comment: Oops. Wait a second. They can just change "rollno" to "studentage" in the above program. I still made the edit.

Answer (score 0):

You said, "s it possible to Sort ? without using implementing Comparator or Comparable in class"

The answer to your question, then, is **Yes**. You can implement a custom Comparator and pass that to this [sort overload](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(T[],%20java.util.Comparator)). You still implement `Comparator`, but not as a member of the class of the items you're sorting.

See [Using comparator to make custom sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245093/using-comparator-to-make-custom-sort) for an example.

Answer (score -2):

Yes its called

```
yourArray.sort();
```

You should copy your Array into a new one (if you want sort only the newArray while the Data of the old one isnt sort) using :

```
System.arraycopy(yourArray, startIndex, newArray, );
```

or you can use

```
int[]newArray = Arrays.copyOf(yourArray, arrayLength);
```

In my Opinion first solution is more powerfull since you are able to merge Arrays.

Comment: It's an `ArrayList`.

Comment: System.arraycopy(yourArray, startIndex, newArray, endIndex);

Comment: Still not getting it. And what's `yourArray.sort()`?

Comment: From my point it doesnt matter, you can use list.sort() and to copy use

Comment: List<> newList = (List<>) yourList.clone()

Comment: Sorry, but this is nonsense. sort( Object[] )  resorts to the natural ordering of the objects -> enter Comparable interface! OP explicitly stated that Comparable shall *not*  be used in any way.